# Creation of view with case when statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select, case-when, create-view

Please refer to my example below for clearer understanding of what i'm doing.

Example:

```
Create View v AS
Select T.*, S.Name, Case When T.TESTDATE = S.STUDYDATE
Then 'Yes' else 'No' END AS TakenTest
From Test T, Student S
Where T.TESTPAPERID = '12345'
And T.StudentNo = S.StudentNo;
```

It create the view successfully. However, it populate duplicate rows with same values like:

```
TESTPAPERID      StudentNo      Name     TakenTest
12345            6437           John     Yes
12345            6437           John     No
```

How can i resolve it as i already define that if T.TESTDATE = S.STUDYDATE then show yes. Otherwise no. And not populating the same values out.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have only one row, use this:

```
MAX(Case When T.TESTDATE = S.STUDYDATE Then 'Yes' else 'No' END)
...
GROUP BY <all other columns, which you haven't shown>
```

Also, this part is poorly coded:

```
T.TESTPAPERID = (Select TESTPAPERID From Student Where TESTPAPERID='12345')
```

because it is IDENTICAL to:

```
T.TESTPAPERID = '12345'
```

Comment: apologize for my mistake. But that statement wont affect the results of duplicating rows.

Comment: While this looks like it solves the problem, having to use grouping or distinct on a query when it doesn't seem appropriate usually flags to me that there are either missing join conditions or duplicate rows. I'd look at properly understanding the data model before adding grouping to a query. But that's just me.

Comment: @MikeyByCrikey you are saying that i missed some join conditions which left me with duplicated rows? I have join all my required attributes from different tables already.